# Setting height of a display:table-cell DIV

Tags: html, css

I want the divs inside to be only 20px height.

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue; display: table">
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:green; display: table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">
            1st cell
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row">
        <div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:red; display: table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">
            2nd cell
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICYAC.png)

Comment: so whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: why the downvote.. my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background:blue; display: table">
    <div style="width:100px;height:20px !important;background:red; 
    display: block;position:absolute; bottom:0; vertical-align:bottom">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/x5hjt74v/

Comment: Firstly, avoid inline css as much as possible.
Use css classes by applying class attribute in your HTML tags .

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your height declaration in your table div.

If you want your table height is 100px, your table-cell div's height will be set to fit the table's height.

```html
<div style="width:100px;background:blue; display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:green; display: table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">
      1st cell
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:red; display: table-cell; vertical-align:bottom">
      2nd cell
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background:blue; display: table">
    <div style="width:100px;height:20px !important; background:red;display:block;vertical-align:bottom">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:100px;background:blue; display: table">
    <div style="width:100px;height:20px;background:red; bottom:0;
    display: block;position:absolute;  vertical-align:bottom">
        Test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Position:absolute; won't work when there's more than one div inside

Comment: Thats a copy of my answer @Gowtham

Comment: I didn't see it sumit,anyhow good answer, i was trying the first one to bring test div on top